# Can not create a map with gmapping

Tags: navigation, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

Im trying to create a map from a bag file using the gmapping. I have done everything using the tutorial http://www.ros.org/wiki/slam_gmapping/Tutorials/MappingFromLoggedData but when I tried to save the map with the map server it was just waited for the map and nothing happened. My bag file has camera, imu and laser scans. The topics are imu/data and scan.

Here is my launch file

```
<param name="/use_sim_time" value="true"/>

<node name="rosplay" pkg="rosbag" type="play" args="/home/2011-04-01-14-19-39.bag  --clock"/>


    <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="baselink_laser" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 /scanmatcher_frame /laser 10"/>
    <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="laser_imu" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 /laser /base_imu 10"/>


    <node pkg="gmapping" type="slam_gmapping" name="slam_gmapping" output="screen">
    <param name="base_frame" value="scanmatcher_frame"/>
        <param name="odom_frame" value="scanmatcher_frame"/>
    <param name="map_frame" value="map"/>
    
</node>

<!-- Start an rviz node with a custom configuration for the viewpoint, map_server, trajectory, laser scans, etc -->
<node pkg="rviz" type="rviz" output="screen" name="rviz" args="-d $(find pow_analyzer)/launch/pow_rviz.vcg"/>
```

Any help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60523/can-not-create-a-map-with-gmapping/) by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on ROS Answers with karma: 330 on 2013-04-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) on 2013-04-12**:
Does your gmapping work? What output does it give?

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2013-04-16**:
No . I can not  get work . I attached the launch file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are missing odometry in the bag file. gmapping requires that to work.

You can try [hector_mapping](http://www.ros.org/wiki/hector_mapping) for a SLAM approach that works without odometry or provide some to gmapping.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-04-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2013-04-17**:
so I need like virtual odometry. I can provide virtual odometry from hector_mapping and feed that to gmapping or??

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-04-17**:
Ideally you need real odometry. If you already have hector_mapping, you shouldn't need to run gmapping on top of that?

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2013-04-17**:
Yes, I already have hector_mapping. So What do you mean to run gmapping on the top of that?? So what do I need??

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-04-17**:
Only one of those. They solve the same problem.

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2013-04-17**:
I do not understand how to run gmapping on the top of hector_mapping. Please can you tell me that??

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-04-17**:
My point is that you should NOT need to do that, unless you know what you want to achieve. The default is to use either one.

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2013-04-17**:
I just wont to compare the two maps from gmapping and hector_mapping and use AMCL and robot_pose_ekf with both of them and also compare the estimated pose. OK?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-04-18**:
The easiest would be to run them one after another on the same log.

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2013-04-18**:
Ok. Just a comment, normally which methods gives a better map??Hector or Gmapping?